# Unable to install and or use auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, auto-py-to-exe

I try to install Auto-Py-to-exe but they have a lot of error appear during the installation but at the end it sais successfully installed, see picture below.
I have windows 10pro, PyCharm community 2020.3.3, and i use python 3.9.1 for almost all my projects.
I have uninstall auto-Py-to-exe, piwin, PYpiwin32, pywin32, PyInstaller. Close all the system and reboot, re-install all these module, but nothing seem to work. It the same error when i use Python 3.6 or 3.7.  the same error arrived in PyCharm terminal and in the promt(cmd) window terminal.

```
C:\Windows\system32>auto-py-to-exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mélissa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,  File "c:\users\mélissa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)  File "C:\Users\Mélissa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\mélissa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 291, in run
    if eel.chrome.get_instance_path() is not None and not disable_chrome:AttributeError: module 'eel.chrome' has no attribute 'get_instance_path'
C:\Windows\system32>
```

I have made the update of PIP, EEL, PYInstaller( the upper version they want to install is 3.2.1, the other fail), gevent and greenlet but i receive always the same error message.

I don't know what to do. I have check here for answer or direction to resolve my problem but i find nothing for now.

[the error message in PYCharm, it the same in window terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WGEN.png)

[image: auto-Py-to-exe successfully installed]
[image: list of module in Python3.9.1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, while looking at the traceback, that the error is in the source code, and not your own execution. Looking through the `auto-py-to-exe` GitHub repository files, it seems that the package just uses `pyinstaller` to convert the python script(s) to executable files. In this case, I would recommend just using `pyinstaller` itself.

To convetr the **.py** file to a single file, run:

```
pyinstaller my_script.py --onefile --windowed
```

The *.exe* file will appear in a folder **dist/** (created during the build). The **build/** folder along with other files created during the process can be deleted.

Comment: If i understand well, i have to go in my PyCharm terminal or cmd windows and write the ligne you tell me. The question, what i do if my programme  have module i  have made or to be clear whit my question how i wrote the line you tell me if they have other module that go whit to run and packages?  for exemple, two modules + the main programme + 2 -3 package.... whit the simple line of code you tell me that will work or i have to write other thing inside the code line. Thank a lot, i appreciate.

Comment: i have try the pyinstaller but i receive this error message:  SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe9' in file C:\Users\Mélissa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller-scri
pt.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Hi again, i have succed to install pyinstaller 4.2 and auto-py-to-exe. i ungrade the wheel (pip install wheel)  But now the error message i receive isfor when i start auto-py-to-exe. is too long for here to writte. But if i understand it is a utf-8 error. It is possible that the É in my name make this error? And it is whay to do to fix that? Thank a lot.

Comment: @MélissaCh. I am not completely sure, but I would not be surprised if that were the case. Try changing the directory name and see if it works.

Comment: I have made a new user, but the problem persist. I ask some advise to my computer technician and they said i have to change in the register, my name and also in some other place,  but is very risky to break up al the system.  So i think i will search for another solution to convect my .py in .exe file. Thank you very much for your time and advise.

Comment: @MélissaCh. You are very much welcome! After all, that's what Stack Overflow is for!